# Qt always says that my screen size is 0

Tags: c++, qt

I have an application that I am trying to make full screen. I have seen on other posts that if I do what in my code, it should give me the size of the screen.

```
double MainSpace::getScopeX(paintBox* window){
  QDesktopWidget temp;
  QRect size = temp.screenGeometry(window);
  return size.width() * window->scale;
}
```

I have a window with a value that changes (scale) so I pass a pointer for that.

Then I use QDesktopWidget::screenGeometry() to get the screen geometry of my window, but the width() and height() methods always return 0! I thought maybe the screen didn't exist in a screen yet so maybe it was returning 0 because there was nothing there, but screenCount() successfully returns 1, so I don't know what's going on. Why does my method always return 0?

Comment: Are you positive `window->scale != 0`? Also, bare in mind that QDesktopWidget needs OS-specific calls to work. Is your OS supported by QDesktopWidget? Also, use `QApplication::desktop()` rather than instantiate your own instance.

Comment: You should read the documentation before posting questions on the internet: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qdesktopwidget.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much more easy. Full Screen is a flag. You can set it as follows:

```
my_widget->setWindowState(Qt::WindowFullScreen);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply open main window in full screen mode by calling `showFullScreen()` instead `show()`:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.showFullScreen();

    return a.exec();
}
```

There is no need to do it manually.